# How to maintain login state using REST web sever?

Tags: java, android, spring, web-services, rest

Normally I can store user's information in session, now I want to develop a application which has both Android client and browser client. So I think I may need a RESTful server. But I got some problems in authentication. Some people suggest that I can use Token mechanism, but I don't know the details about this and can't find many useful information.

I got some questions.

1. Where should I store Token in browser and Android client? Should I use cookie?
2. How to generate Token?
3. How do server verify Token? Should server store Token?
4. Is there any other way in authentication?

I use spring mvc and hibernate. It will help me a lot If anyone can give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Well the general idea is that when the user logins (calls the login endpoint of your api) you generate a random token that you save in the server (in relation to the user) and return to the caller (android). 
All other calls will also require this code which you will compare with the one you have saved. You can also have the code timeout after a duration and depending on your needs, encode it with a predefined key for a bit of added security.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does "save in server" means save it in database or somewhere else?

Comment: database, along with the user it is meant for